# The JS Array used for the second time has length equals '0' but contained objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Description:

- Two arrays (`arrNumber` a number array and `arrString` a string array).
- The `arrNumber` used to add a list of object with the key (number or char) and counter of repeated values.

Problem:

- The first time the `arrDuplicateValues` is OK but in the second time, the array has length equals 0 but has items.

https://jsbin.com/qevuxopoma/edit?js,console

```js
var arrNumber = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0 ,4, 6, 8, 4];
var arrString = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "a", "i", "u", "i"];

var arrDuplicateValues = new Array();
// Fist time: Only number
arrNumber.forEach(x => {
  arrDuplicateValues[x] = (arrDuplicateValues[x] || 0) + 1;
});
console.log(arrDuplicateValues); // OK


// Second time: With string
arrDuplicateValues = new Array();
arrString.forEach(x => {
  arrDuplicateValues[x] = (arrDuplicateValues[x] || 0) + 1;
});
console.log(arrDuplicateValues); // NOK
console.log(arrDuplicateValues["i"]);
```

Comment: Arrays use numeric indices for elements. Using strings just adds properties to the object but doesn't add elements to the array.

Comment: You shouldn't really be using an array unless you want to have numerically-indexed properties in sequence. Your second example just adds string keys. These exist on the array object, but do not add to its length.

Comment: Don't use `new Array()` (it almost certainly does not do what you think it does), use the normal JS syntax for allocating a new array: `var/let/const thing = [];`. Also, arrays are indexed lists in JS, arrays are not  like PHP where they can be both indexed or "associative arrays" (taking string keys): in JS the basic datatype for string keyed data is the object, which uses `{}` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be using objects rather than arrays here. Because arrays are lists with an index.

Working example:

```js
var arrNumber = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0 ,4, 6, 8, 4];
var arrString = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "a", "i", "u", "i"];

var arrDuplicateValues = {};
// Fist time: Only number
arrNumber.forEach(x => {
  arrDuplicateValues[x] = (arrDuplicateValues[x] || 0) + 1;
});
console.log(arrDuplicateValues); // OK


// Second time: With string
arrDuplicateValues = {};
arrString.forEach(x => {
  arrDuplicateValues[x] = (arrDuplicateValues[x] || 0) + 1;
});
console.log(arrDuplicateValues); // NOK
console.log(arrDuplicateValues["i"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`arrDuplicateValues` is an object the second time, cause array doesn't have a string index. So though you initialized it an Array(), it eventually became a map(key-value pair) hence when you just tried to print the entire map it yeilded nothing. If you just change the initialization to `arrDuplicateValues = {};` second time , it works fine.

```
var arrNumber = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0 ,4, 6, 8, 4];
var arrString = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "a", "i", "u", "i"];

var arrDuplicateValues = new Array();
// Fist time: Only number
arrNumber.forEach(x => {
  arrDuplicateValues[x] = (arrDuplicateValues[x] || 0) + 1;
});
console.log(arrDuplicateValues); // OK


// Second time: With string
arrDuplicateValues = {};
arrString.forEach(x => {
  arrDuplicateValues[x] = (arrDuplicateValues[x] || 0) + 1;
});
console.log(arrDuplicateValues); // NOK
console.log(arrDuplicateValues["i"]);
```